# Should I 'Accept' answers that are "you can't do this", and if so When?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If my question was "How do I achieve <this>", or "How can I improve <this> process, instead of using <this> hacky solution I've constructed".

Suppose the first answer I get is:

> You can't; what you've done is the best available option.

On the one hand, that answer hasn't really helped me.
Unless the person cites (or is!) an authority on the particular subject, all it actually says is "I (the answerer) *also* don't know of any way to achieve that". The fact that one other person on the internet also doesn't know how to solve this tells me very little.

On the other hand, eventually the absence of any alternate answers becomes circumstantial evidence that there genuinely isn't a way to achieve this. In which case I will mentally "accept" that there isn't any way to do this, and move on with my life :) In which case this answer is correct, and should be rewarded and the record provided for the next user.

So ...

**Should I 'Accept' this answer?**

If so ... when? What's a sensible period of time to wait for another person to come along who *does* know a way to achieve it?

Comment: It's up to you. It's understandable that without additional details the answer may not look useful to you. You can prompt the answerer to add information with a comment. That's what comments are for.

Comment: All that boils down to "That answer hasn't really helped me." and that's the point: if it didn't help you, then don't award if with an upvote or an accept vote. No one forces you to select an answer, especially not one that didn't even help you. Instead give the question more time to receive other answers or think about a bounty to attract more.

Comment: I assume it is your latest question, I'll not link to it since you chose yourself not to do that. Your question is a little... off. Clearly what you want to ask is "Can I do a rename?" since that takes the problem of data transfer performance out of the picture entirely, but then you toss it around and make it a vague "Can I do a copy faster?". A little X/Y problemish.

Comment: @Gimby agreed. It wasn't a well constructed question, which was why I didn't link it - I don't think it's a great example.

Comment: Votes are the grease that keep the SO wheel turning.  There is very little grease in the [azure] community.  Nobody earns any real rep, certainly not Leon.  You *really* want an answer from the [top contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/stopped-contributing), but that's not going to happen.

Comment: I just want to say that sometimes the answer "this is not possible" is actually really helpful.

Comment: I typically don't accept "that's not possible" answers, not necessarily because they aren't helpful but because several times I've asked or seen questions to which the correct answer *at that time* was "it's not possible", but then down the line a feature or package was added that made it possible.

Comment: @PGmath The accepted marker is not carved in stone. You can accept a different, newer answer any time you want. So the possibility of future changes is not a reason not to accept an answer today.

Comment: @holger technically yes, I know you can change which answer is accepted.  But that doesn't change the fact that if the question is marked as answered it makes it significantly less likely that anyone will give the question any further attention down the line.  Leaving it unanswered means it is more likely to pop up on someone's radar down the line to answer if a solution has become possible.

Comment: My recommendation for the time to wait would be at least 24 hours, since that gives people in every time zone a chance to see and answer the question.

Comment: There's a difference between not knowing a better solution to an answer and being confident that there is not better solution to an answer. When I'm answering questions I can generally tell right off the bat whether I'm clueless about the topic subject or whether I might have something to contribute, and it's a separate step to actually looking for an answer.

Comment: `There's a difference between not knowing a better solution to an answer and being confident that there is not better solution to an answer.` I assume that you've heard of Duning Kruger :) Not saying it's true of you, but "someone on the internet confidently asserts that they know it can't be done" just isn't reliable info.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any answer -- across the Stack Exchange network -- should give enough reasons to understand why the author comes to that conclusion. If convincing reasons are given and nobody came up with a better solution, by all means upvote and accept. Obviously, the expertise of the answerer also plays a role in judging the answer, even though we should not blindly trust high reputations.

If the reasons are lacking or doubtful or you just don't want to accept it as the final truth, **create a bounty!** That should attract attention to the question and elicit more and hopefully different responses, or at least additional explanations.

I would trust an existing answer after I have offered a bounty to no avail.

Answer (score 42):

**Accept the answer whenever you feel so, or don't accept it at all.**

Acceptance only means that it helps *the asker* the best. It doesn't even mean it's the best answer for everyone. The voting will (usually) take care of the quality of the answers.

If the existing answers don't satisfy the issue, feel free to post some comments if appropriate, but users are not forced to accept any answers they receive.

However, *users can also un-accept the answer and accept another answer* if they later receive answers that are more helpful than the currently accepted answer.

Note though that some potential answerers may be reluctant to read questions that already have an accepted answer, so it's a bit of a gamble to accept a less-than-satisfactory answer.

---

Further reading: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: “*Note though that some potential answerers may reluctant to read questions that already have an accepted answer, so it's a bit gambling to accept the non-satisfactory answer.*” But further note that these people might downvote a question for wasting their time, when they discover that the question without an accepted answer actually has been well answered, so not accepting the answer despite it says everything that is to say about the topic, also is some kind of gambling.

Comment: @Holger Why would you (read: anyone) downvote a question for not having accepted a good answer? The two seem completely unrelated - what if I asked a question, got a great answer the next day but was then on holiday for 2 weeks? I'd think their priorities are misplaced if someone's threshold for time-wasting is *clicking a link, realising there's an answer, pressing back*.

Comment: @Wolfie dumping a question on SO when you know you’re going on a two-weeks holiday, can be considered misbehavior too. This site is dedicate to solve programming problems, not “programming questions I actually don’t care about”. Too often, people dump questions on SO and go away immediately, not responding on any request for clarifications. So harsh reactions are not surprising. Though, it doesn’t matter whether you think the downvote is justified. It’s the same freedom, for both sides. You can accept an answer or not, as you like, and other people can downvote for whatever reason they like.

Comment: @Holger I'm not trying to argue that you don't have the freedom to downvote whatever you choose, was just trying to understand your perspective. I understand where you're coming from as a frequent SO user, but if I were to relate this to how I treat emails to colleagues with questions, I'm not going to watch my inbox for replies; rather I'm going to go and do something productive and check back for an answer (some time) later. The Q&A might be useful to anyone in CC (i.e. public SO users) regardless whether or not I confirm their answer.

Comment: Recently had a leading/correct answer unaccepted and the the guy who asked posted his own answer, which merely replicated the content of my answer ...and those accepted answers are often not so good as they may appear at first (that green check-mark is not always accurate, and so I have lots of necromancer badges). The voting is indeed often more accurate than the initially accepted answer; one has to consider that people may just move on, once they have something averagely acceptable.

Comment: @Holger It does matter, actually, whether a downvote or upvote is justified, because upvotes and downvotes are how we do quality control on this site, and it's important that that process is effective for the health of the community.

Comment: The fact that the question asker got an answer is almost a sideshow. The real goal is building up the repository for everyone who needs an answer.

Answer (score 9):

It is entirely up to you whether you accept or not any Answers.  (And people should not pressure you to accept Answers!)

So, speaking for myself ...

If I got a one sentence Answer like that, I would not accept it.  Or even upvote it.  It is a low quality Answer.

On the other hand, if I would be inclined to accept an Answer that says "You can't do that" or "You shouldn't do that", and then explains why.

Assuming that I understand the explanation, and find it convincing, then the Answer *has helped me*.  It has probably saved me time trying to get something to work that won't work, or that might cause me other problems later on.  Or it has corrected some misconception that will help me in the future.

Of course, this reasoning requires a bit of introspection ... to *realise* that a disappointing Answer (not the one I wanted to hear) can be helpful to me.

---

How long to wait?  That again is entirely up to you.

If it was me, I would be "strategic" about it.  Experts are less likely to spend time on a Question with an accepted Answer.  So accepting too soon *may* reduce the chance that you will get a Better Answer.

Admittedly, I ask so few questions that I don't have a good feel for the best strategy.

Comment: Certainly agree, if that were the *entirety* of the answer, or if the additional comments ae an argument for *why* it can't be done. But normally what you get is "It can't be done ... and here are some *other* things you might want to do based on my guess of the XY problem that I assume you have, or an argument for why I don't think you should be doing it at all". ... which make it a higher quality answer, but don't actually increase the compellingness of the claim "It can't be done".

Comment: As I said: "Assuming that I understand the explanation, **and find it convincing** ...".

Comment: fair :) Just having a bit of a grumble :)

Answer (score 4):

I've found myself in the situation where I've gotten poorly explained/researched answers that turn out to match my subsequent findings in the area.  I'm not sure if this is good or accepted practice, but what I've done in that case is write up my findings as my own answer, including evidence or noting the general lack thereof, and accept that.  I don't think having an answer state "no, this is impossible" without anything backing it up is particularly helpful, so it doesn't make a good accepted answer.  I might still upvote their answer as useful, though, especially if it pointed me down the right track in figuring it out.

If I or someone else do come along with a way to achieve the goal in the future, I'll just switch my accepted answer, assuming I feel the approach is a sensible one.